# VBA code keeps skipping my Find.Execute Code

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ms-word, find

I am new to VBA and I and working on a code to copy data from Excel to Word by finding keywords and replacing them. My problem is the code creates a new version of the document I want to copy, but then ignores my code to find and replace. I think my issue is with my declarations, but I really have no idea. Here is my code:

```
Sub CopyDatatoWord()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim wdDoc As Word.Documents
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim myrange As Range

Set wb = Workbooks("Create Health Fair Forms.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Data")

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set sel = wdApp.Selection

MkDir ("" & ws.Range("FilePath").Value & "")

wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
wdApp.Documents.Open("\\hfd\repository\Screenings and Health Fair Forms\Basic Health Fair Templates\013 - CW - Template.docm", Visible = True, ReadOnly = False).SaveAs ("" & ws.Range("FilePath").Value & "\CW.docm")
wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
wdApp.Visible = True

'Code works fine until this point, and then seems to ignore everything past this point.

For i = 13 To 30

With wdApp.Selection.Find
 .Text = "&Excel.Application.ws.Cells(i, 40).Value&"
 .Forward = True
 .Wrap = wdFindContinue
 .MatchWholeWord = True
 .Format = False
 .Replacement.Text = "&Excel.Application.ws.Cells(i, 39).Value&"
 .Execute
 End With

Next i
End Sub
```

I have seen other posts online where people have successfully created a code like mine, and I have been trying to recreate it, but have so far failed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you walk through the Macro? In VBA, put the mouse cursor anywhere in your code, and press `F8`.  After `wdApp.Visible = True`, what happens? Does it just jump to `End Sub`?

Comment: Your Find is looking for the string "Excel.Application.ws.Cells(i, 40).Value&" which isn't what you want. Try removing the quotes and the ampersands.

Comment: I have walked through it. It loops through the find code, but it does not do anything. I have played around with it since, and just told it to find a string ("Name") and replace it with another string. It Finds "Name" in my document, but then does not replace it. (Before it did not find anything).

Comment: Also, made one change to the code, I had Content.Find.Execute at the end of the find code. I had meant to remove the Content.Find, but missed it before I pasted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very stinky code

```
 .Text = "&Excel.Application.ws.Cells(i, 40).Value&"
 .Replacement.Text = "&Excel.Application.ws.Cells(i, 39).Value&"
```

It should probably be something like

```
 .Text = ws.Cells(i, 40).Value
 .Replacement.Text = ws.Cells(i, 39).Value
```

Also When i record a macro to do a find an repalce it give the following code 
The lines marked '<<<<<<<<   need adjusting and adding to your code

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting    '<<<<<<<<
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting   '<<<<<<<<
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "d"
    .Replacement.Text = "XXXX"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False  '<<<<<<<<
    .MatchSoundsLike = False  '<<<<<<<<
    .MatchAllWordForms = False  '<<<<<<<<
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll  '<<<<<<<<
```

Comment: This helps, it now finds the strings, but then it does not replace them. If I click the through the code just keeps moving through the document, finding each string, but not doing anything else.

Comment: please tick my answer and use the up arrow to like it.